# Testing react-router v4 with jest and enzyme always got .404 component

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jestjs, react-router-v4

For some reason, I can't reach router in my tests.

My render in main container:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="AppEntry-scope">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
            // ...Other routes

            <Route component={FourOhFourNothinFound} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

My test:

```
describe('<Dashboard />', () => {
  it('Should see dashboard', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
        <AppEntry store={store} />
      </MemoryRouter>,
    );

    expect(wrapper.find(Dashboard)).toBePresent();
  });
});
```

Also, I've tried:

```
expect(wrapper.find(Dashboard).length).toBe(1);
```

And my test doesn't see Dashboard component.

In my app this route is works, but I want to set up test for routes.

BTW, when I tried to test my notfound component FourOhFourNothinFound - it works and seems my tests always see notfound component.

What is wrong and how I can set up my react-router tests correctly?

Comment: What's the code inside the `<AppEntry />` ?